# Sitecore multi layered tagging

Tags: sitecore, taxonomy

I am working on some tagging infrastructure for my client. There is need to have tagging for the following - Regions, Countries, Cities and Office Locations.

Items in the content tree can be tagged for only region, country or city. But there also needs to exist relationship between the above tags as follows

Regions --> Countries --> Cities --> Office Locations.

The relationship between cities and office locations can be many to many.

I can pursue the above relationship by having 4 separate lists - one each for regions, countries, cities and offices.

Then I can follow two modes of tagging

EITHER

On the Office tag item, there can be a multilist field for a city tag and multiple cities could be selected that way for an office. Then the city tag can have a multilist field for selecting countries, and country tag can have a multilist for regions. The region item would not have any fields.

OR

A region tag can have a multilist field to select countries, a country tag can have a field to select cities, a city can have multilist field for offices, and offices won't have any fields.

Which method is preferable and why?

I do not want to do a hierarchical structure as that would not sit well with many to many relationship issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation, it feels like the second (top-down) approach is the one you should go with.

I'd do it for a couple of reasons:

1. In your first option, you mention an Office would have a multilist for multiple cities.  Would an Office location really have multiple cities?  I would think that an office location should only have a single city associated with it, which would point me to the top-down approach.
2. The top-down approach just makes more sense logically.  Look at the way you described your tagging relationship:

> Regions --> Countries --> Cities --> Office Locations.

You're already describing it that way and I think it would make more sense to then architect it that way as well.

Comment: One office multiple cities can be used in case we decide to use metro areas so metro DC area would include Northern Virginia, DC and Maryland.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  In that case, do you want to not use "Cities" and use something like "areas" instead?  That way, you won't be limited by the city.

Comment: I don't think there is a 'right' answer to this. You just need to think about which will be easier to maintain.

Comment: You are right there is no right answer for this but based on user experience I decided to go with Craig's recommendation as that seems less work for them in terms of tagging.